# macOS Big Sur Startup Error - "Backup and Restore has Encountered a Fatal Error"

Tags: big-sur

I have been getting this error message constantly upon startup:

[image]

From some quick research, I found out that this might be related to permission issues for `Google` directory in `Application Support`. So I went in and typed the following:

```
 sudo chmod -R 755 ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google
```

Upon restart, it still creeped in. I am not sure what this problem is anymore. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

OK solved it! I wish Google named the application a little differently e.g. "Google Backup" instead of "Backup and Sync from Google" - compact naming.

1. Identify where the application is i.e. `Applications` folder
2. Delete the application and restart Mac - SUCCESS, no more error!
3. Now, google for Google Drive application and download the individual version. It's smart enough to know that your OS is Mac and will push the correct installer for you.
4. Run it, install it, and check from Finder that Google Drive is visible.

All done and working in Big Sur now!